# Do certain window properties have special writable attribute rules?

Tags: javascript

Does the global window object have special rules on some of its properties? For example, it seems that you are unable to set event properties/methods to anything other than a function:

```
console.log(window.onclick) // null

window.onclick = 1;
console.log(window.onclick) // null (?)
```

There doesn't seem to be anything extraordinary about the property attributes of `onclick`:

```
console.dir(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'onclick'));

*/ returns {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    value: null,
    writable: true
  } */
```

But if you set window.onclick to a function the property is changed as expected:

```
window.onclick = function() {
  alert();
};
console.log(window.onclick); // logs: function() { alert(); }
```

Comment: `window.onclick` is a pre-existing property on a host object that has a specific purpose (an event handler for click events that bubble to the `window` object).  It very well could be that it does not let you set it to something that isn't a function since that wouldn't be a valid event handler.  `window` is a host object and host objects often have special behaviors (since they are not 100% javascript in their implementation and are not governed by the ECMAScript spec).

Comment: *window* is a host object and largely implementation dependent. Whatever behaviour you discover in one host may be different in another, or not.

Comment: Event handlers don't accept non-functions. Regular elements act the same: https://jsfiddle.net/6tbk31ad/

Comment: @AndrewL.- is that just common knowledge or is this documented somewhere?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @guest271314 - an understanding of why this is happening.

Comment: @AndrewL.—do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @jfriend00 - you're making an assumption that I'm trying to do this in some production application. I'm simply trying to understanding why I was seeing something unexpected. And don't tell me what to learn!

Comment: `try {
Object.defineProperty(window, "onclick", {
  prototype:null,
  __proto__: null,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
  get: function() {return 1}
}) } catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}`

Comment: The answer is simple.  It's a host object that is free to control what is or isn't accepted as an assigned property.  In the specific case you are trying, it is rejecting anything that is not a function because the property has no practical use if it's not a function.  Because it's a host object, it can follow it's own rules.  It is not plain Javascript.  There is no more of an answer than that.

Comment: According to the [*Living Standard*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#events), on setting the property should just be set to the supplied value. However, the algorithm for what happens when getting the listener means it needs to be either a callable object (a function or method) or raw code that compiles (depending on how it was set). So it doesn't make sense to allow a non–function when setting the property directly (i.e. the "IDL attribute"). But that is just the browser being nice, it's not specified anywhere.